# Как правильно построить предложение? 2

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сейчас уже давно стало хорошей традицией...

Answer (score 2):

В этом предложении нежелательно одновременно употреблять наречия "давно и сейчас", что касается "уже", то это слово  здесь является усилительной частицей. Выбор зависит от контекста:

(1) Сейчас уже стало хорошей традицией... (2) Давно уже  стало хорошей традицией... .

**УЖЕ**. I.  II. частица. 3. Усиливает значимость слов и словосочетаний, с которыми связано по смыслу. **У. давно уехал кто-л.**